# Barplot clean up x-axis label

Tags: r, plot

I am using a crime data set from kaggle and I am trying to create a simple `barplot` which plots the crime type on x axis and how frequency the crime was committed on y axis. Although because there are a lot of crime types, the x axis is very messy. I did some research on how to make the labels vertical although they still are unreadable.

Are there any other ways I can clean this plot up without editing all of the crime names? My current code is:

```
tab2 <- table(crimeData$Crime.Code.Description)
barplot(tab2,main="Crime Areas",las=2)
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like a classic case of [overplotting](https://www.displayr.com/what-is-overplotting/). There are a couple of ways to deal with this -either group your data into related topics (e.g. speeding, failure to stop, etc all fall under group of traffic), then break up into smaller sub-plots. Or you can plot only those that are significant for your point(set a cut-off point, maybe 25000 in your case). Check out ggplot2 - it can help you a lot with axis labels.

Comment: cheers for the reply. how would i set a cut off point of 25000 for example?

Comment: Something like `tab2 <- table(crimeData$Crime.Code.Description >=25000)` should work

Comment: thanks again for the reply. i tried this and got the following error message: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(crimeData$Crime.Code.Description, 25000) :
  ‘>=’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: It's a little hard to trouble shoot without a minimal data set, but factors in R are categorical integers associated as a character - check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-integer-numeric-without-loss-of-information) for a solution.

Comment: i'm using this data set: https://www.kaggle.com/cityofLA/crime-in-los-angeles

Comment: In that case you can convert the code description into counts as you did for tab2: `tab2 <-table(crimeData$Crime.Code.Description)` then `tab3 <- subset(tab2, tab2 >=25000)`, then barplot as above using `tab3`.

Comment: thanks bob, worked perfect! last question; would it be possible for me to rename the values of tab3? as the labels are still very long and need to be narrowed down to fit on x axis i.e. 'VANDALISM - FELONY ($400 & OVER, ALL CHURCH VANDALISMS) 0114'  need to be narrowed down to 'VANDALISM'

Comment: look at the `cex.names` function in `?barplot`. You should be able to provide a character vector to do this. Another option is possibly to use the `substr` command to shorten and use a regular expression to capture only the first word, or perhaps break the name over 1 or more columns, so that the first word from the name is all that is left in one column.